# PHP-7: mysqli_result::data_seek(): Function cannot be used with MYSQL_USE_RESULT

Tags: php, mysqli

Code is running a prepared query.  Code more-or-less looks like this:

```
  $sth = $conn->prepare('select foo from bar');
  $sth->execute();
  $result = $sth->store_metadata();  // since prepared-query ...
  $sth->store_result();              // returns TRUE = successful
  echo $sth->num_rows();             // returns, say, '4'
  $sth->data_seek(0);                // gives warning
```

The `data_seek()` function gives this warning:

`mysqli_result::data_seek(): Function cannot be used with MYSQL_USE_RESULT`

Looking at the PHP source-code on GitHub, and related comments, it appears that this message is produced when the result is "un-buffered."

However, at this point, it is my understanding that the result-set *should* be "buffered," because I asked to store the result, and `store_result()` returned **true** to indicate success.  (Further evidence is that `num_rows()` returns a non-zero *(and, indeed, correct ...)* result.)

It is important to this (hoary, old) application that `data_seek()` must work. I thought that I was already doing everything right.  But, what am I doing wrong?  *(The use of non-prepared queries is not an option.)*

Comment: Using get_result is not an option too, I suppose?

Comment: It appeared to me that "get_result" was not correct for prepared statements – per "http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.metadata.php" – but I'm not sure I really believe that anymore . . . There are grotesque inconsistencies in the official documentation.

Comment: Right now, I am =also= seeing an apparent difference between parameterized and non-parameterized queries:  a parameterized query is returning no results.  Also:  if I do use "get_result()," which suggests in the documentation that it returns a buffered result-set, "row_count()" returns zero.  ("affected count" does not.)  However, I do notice that, when I use "get_result," data-seek does work.  So, I've got a weird combination going on here, sort of "damned if I do, and damned if I don't" between the various possibilities.